# AWS PDF upload through http post

Tags: http, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS and I am trying to upload a pdf document to S3 trough an AWS API. I am using an HTML form with a post method. The action of the form is the URL of the deployed API. The API is integrated with a lambda function. My question is how can I extract the uploaded file to proceed within the lambda function, to perform some processing before uploading to S3. Is it even possible?

I have tried the instructions found in this post:
[Passing HTTP Post from AWS API GW to Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381995/passing-http-post-from-aws-api-gw-to-lambda)

However, I return the event from the lambda function and this is what I get:

```
{file: file.pdf , acl:private,
success_action_redirect: http://localhost/, AWSAccessKeyId:my_aws_key}
```

The file I uploaded is called file.pdf.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pdf file is a binary format.  API Gateway does not currently support binary data.  We know that binary data does not work and there are no  workarounds to make it work reliably.  A number of customers have requested that we add binary support to API Gateway and it is prioritized on our backlog.

Comment: Thanks. What if the file is zipped. Will it go through?

Comment: No, a zipped file will not work as that is also binary.  You could base64 encode the pdf on the client, pass the base64 encoded data through API Gateway to your Lambda function, decode the data in your Lambda function, and upload it to S3 from there.  Obviously, this would require custom code on your client to do the base64 encode.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS Thanks a lot!